# git commit failed .No secret key

Tags: git, github

```
> git -c user.useConfigOnly=true commit --quiet --allow-empty-message --file - -S
gpg: skipped "2FE08EC7CD33715B": No secret key
gpg: signing failed: No secret key
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

this is the key

```
$ gpg --list-keys
/c/Users/username/.gnupg/pubring.kbx
-------------------------------------
pub   rsa3072 2023-10-01 [SC] [expires: 2025-09-30]
      8E8E32E954E6551C044D3AA72FE08EC7CD33715B
uid           [ultimate] username123<name@gmail.com>
sub   rsa3072 2023-10-01 [E] [expires: 2025-09-30
```

I still have doubt is there a key in the above snippet.any help or suggestion

git commit to github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `gpg --list-keys` command you ran is showing your *public* keys, make sure  the private key is indeed available on your system and is accessible to the GPG installation that Git is using.

As explained in "[GitHub / Checking for existing GPG keys](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/managing-commit-signature-verification/checking-for-existing-gpg-keys)", Use the command `gpg --list-secret-keys` to display all the private keys on your system. Look for the private key associated with the public key `2FE08EC7CD33715B`.

If the private key for `2FE08EC7CD33715B` is not listed, you will need to import or generate a new private key: `gpg --import /path/to/your-private-key.gpg`

Double-check Git is configured to use the correct GPG key by default. You can set the GPG key to be used by Git with `git config --global user.signingkey 2FE08EC7CD33715B`

Comment: i configured gpg key on my github and also global gpg.program  with command "where gpg.exe" which was i side git.above message helped to verify things and i went through the link you provided to know more .Thank you so much .

Comment: @deepaksp Great! Does it work now?

Comment: Yes it's working fine. Thanks again